# Batch edit multiple entities in GAE's datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, batch-file, entity, google-cloud-datastore

How can I batch-edit entities?

In GAE's data viewer, I can click on a single entity, and then manually type in, and replace any of its values. But how can I do this for multiple (thousands of) entities at once?

I just want to find each entity which have a particular string among its values and replace it with another.

I don't see any controls for this in GAE's dashboard/data-viewer. Or maybe it's possible to accomplish this in-app?  It's in python, if that makes a difference...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [remote API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api) which lets you interact with the datastore from the comfort of your SDK. You can do something like this:

```
q = MyModel.all()
for entity in q:
    # Do your search-and-replace operation on entity
```

There are caveats regarding performance and the number of entities you can fetch at once, so do read the article.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot batch-edit entities like you can in a normal SQL server. Possible solutions:

1. Write your own migration method and call it yourself if you don't have too many entities (in the few thousands).
2. [MapReduce](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/overview), which can do work in parallel.
3. Use the remote API, as discussed in the other answer.